# React bootstrap dropdown cannot read property 'Item'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using React-Bootstrap for the dropdown but it is not render in chrome. I got an error message. It seems that I am not able to use Dropdown.Item even if I've already import the Dropdown component.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Item' of undefined
>       at MenuItem.render (MenuItem.tsx:20)
>       at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13538)
>       at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13501)
>       at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:14090)
>       at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:16416)
>       at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:16454)
>       at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:145)
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:195)
>       at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:248)
>       at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:15745)

Here is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
import DropdownButton from 'react-bootstrap/DropdownButton';

export interface Props {
    name: string;
}

export class MenuItem extends React.Component<Props> {
constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="wc-menuitem">
            <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Dropdown button">
            <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
            </DropdownButton>
        </div>
    );
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just pasted your code in to a sandbox and it seems fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-glade-5l30x

Comment: Which version of react-bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @max23_ The version I used is 1.0.0-beta.9

Comment: It works fine for me too. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ae22xx